# Lift: Sending notifications to the client from within a Future

Tags: scala, concurrency, lift

In lift, I have a page that accepts a few files to be uploaded, and then processes the files (which takes around a minute+) I don't want to make users wait the full minute just to see another page, so I decided to put the processing work into a `Future` object. My end goal is to send the user a link to the results page once the processing is done.

Here's the gist of my code:

```
Futures.future {
  doLongLastingProcessing
  val linkXml = makeLinkToResults
  println("Hey I'm done!")
  S.notice(linkXml)
}
```

The problem I get is that any S-related stuff done within the Future doesn't seem to work. The work finishes and I see the "Hey I'm done" in the console, but get no notice.

How can I get a "completion" notice to the user (even if they've navigated away from the upload page) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at Lift's [CometActors](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Comet_Support) and sending a message to the appropriate CometActor from the Future. Or you might just want to drop the Future entirely and just use Actors.

Be aware that there are a few gotchas (e.g. [not having access to `S`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915259/scala-lift-s-param-access-within-comet-actor/7915563#7915563)) but it sounds like your CometActor can just return a normal response. I just checked the wiki, and apparently you do have [access to `S.notice` within your CometActor](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Comet_and_S).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that shows how to do what you are asking using comet actors [post](http://blog.fmpwizard.com/54204619)