# Scala Lift - Comet actor initialization message

Tags: scala, comet, lift

I have the following Comet actor:

```
class ChatComet extends CometActor with CometListener {

    private var messages: List[ChatItem] = Nil 

    def registerWith = ChatServer

    override def lowPriority = {

        case v: List[ChatItem] => 

        messages = v; 
        reRender()

    }

    def render = {

        "li *" #> messages.map(message =>

            ".name *" #> message.name &
            ".text *" #> message.value

    )

}
```

Which distributes messages around various rooms, what I don't have is a way to limit which messages end up where, so a message from RoomA ends up in RoomA not in RoomB.

I've heard you can initialize comet actors with some kind of message which in my case could serve as the room id.

Is this the right way of doing things? If so how would I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template, name the comet actor, like so:

```
 <div class="l:comet?type=CometActor;name=roomA"> stuff </div>
```

In your CometActor, then match on the name, like so:

```
    def lowpriority = {
       case NewComment(room, msg) => {
      name.map(x => x match {
        case "roomA" => {
          stuff
        }
    }
  }
```

Now, you probably don't have explicit names like "roomA" but you can keep a list of your room names, and then simply match against them.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, I'm aiming to have alot of rooms (hundreds) which are dynamically generated, is there a way I can dynamically add this param?

Comment: Yes, use a snippet to generate the comet actor.

Answer (score 0):

Give your Comet Actors names associated with the chat rooms.  Then a new Actor will be built per-room.  You won't need to do any special handling in your Actor itself; unless you want to have special features depending on the room.

You can see [a nice example](https://github.com/dpp/starting_point/tree/named_comet_fun) referenced [on the Lift wiki](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Named_Comet), which shows how you can use a snippet to assign the names to your Comet Actors.

Answer (score 0):

For initializing CometActors in general, check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915259/scala-lift-s-param-access-within-comet-actor/7915563#7915563) on `S.param` within a CometActor. That being said, Dave and Tyler's answers seem more appropriate to what you want to do.