# How can I set dynamically the parameter of a lift snippet?

Tags: scala, lift

Is there a way I can modify dynamically the param of a snippet?

E.g. If I call this URL

```
host:port/a_page?name=myname
```

I would like that my page look like this:

```
<div class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">
   <div class="lift:comet?type=MySnippet;name=myname" >
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Is that even possible? I tried using some javascript in order to extract the param from the url and putting it in the `class` attribute of the `div` but in my understanding that won't work becase the scripts will always execute after lift framework does it's magic.

Thanks in advance! Any help is really appreciated.

---

I used both tips provided to make it work, like ajantis mentioned reading the param directly from snippet is the easiest way but doesnt work in a comet call. Rogach solution works.

So the solution is:

```
<div class="lift:Ex.wrap">
  <div id="myid"></div>
</div>

def wrap = { 
val name = "lift:comet?type=MySnippet;name=" + S.param("name").openOr("...")            
"#myid" #> <div id="myid" class={name} ></div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try wrapping that comet snippet in other snippet, which would transform xml and add that `name=myname` to `class`. Like:

```
<div class="lift:Ex.wrap">
  <div class="lift:comet?type=MySnippet"></div>
</div>

class Ex {
  def wrap = { (n: NodeSeq) =>
    // example transformation
    // AntiXML syntax
    import com.codecommit.antixml._;
    val comet = n \ "div" head;
    val comet2 = 
      comet.copy(attrs = comet.attrs +
                         ("class" -> (comet.attrs("class") + ";name=myname")))
    n \ "div" updated (0, comet2) unselect
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Rogach, I amused with lift community. Is really small but full of bright and helpful people.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just extract http parameter inside snippet processing? i.e.

```
def render = {
   val name = S.param("name").openOr("...")
....
}
```

Comment: It's a comet snippet (in OP's example) - at the very least, it does not seem to have proper access to S.param.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. Then i would suggest this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915259/scala-lift-s-param-access-within-comet-actor/7915563#7915563

Comment: thanx @ajantis ,Rogach solution is a little easier than the propoused in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915259/scala-lift-s-param-access-within-comet-actor/7915563#7915563 but I couldn't have got the answer without your help.